# Using .strip() to create dictionary from txt file

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to python. My first task is to create a dictionary from a table in .txt file (input file).
When I print the input file in python

```
>temp = open ("input.txt", 'r')
>temp.readlines()
['Traget1\t\score1\r\n', 'Target2\tscore2\r\n', .... 'Target26\tscore26']
```

I tried to create dictionary:
`

```
temp = open ("input.txt", 'r')
 d = {}
 for line in temp.readlines():
     target, score = line.split("\t")
     d[target] = float (score)
 print d
```

`

Result:
{'Target1 : score 1', 'Target2 : score2', .... 'Target26 : score26'}

The dictionary was created, however, I came across some code that use .strip() to remove the characters \r\n from each line of the input file. I am confused why I do not have to include .strip() and still get to create the dictionary?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

`score` will contain the trailing newline character(s), but that's not a problem, as `float()` accepts it:

```
>>> float("35\r\n")
35.0
```

Now, if you had a string there (e.g.: in your example the two fields were a reverse order) you had a problem.

Note: your example of what's in the file is *extremely* misleading. `float` is the only hint that you have numbers there.